# SPF not verified

Tags: mailgun

I have some email service additional to mailgun that automatically sets SPF record in DNS. There is option to add extra host to this SPF record however it does not make domain verified...

My SPF record looks like this:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:11.11.11.11 +include:mailgun.org ~all
```

I've tested it with http://www.mail-tester.com/spf-dkim-check and SPF record exists. However in mailgun manager when I click "Check DNS records now" it complains about SPF (DKIM / CNAME are OK). What can I do? I can't edit SPF record manually because it is auto-genarated by other email service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying, it sounds like your SPF is OK. Send an email from Mailgun using this [Mail tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/), it will tell you if the SPF Passes. I'm wondering if MailGun has an issues with the "+" qualifier, it's the default and is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary spf record should end with -all. ~all is used for testing (SoftFail).
The ip address with the most mail traffic should be in your first spf record.

-all (Fail) for production systems

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:11.11.11.11 include:mailgun.org -all
```

optimized for ip 11.11.11.11 reduced dns queries

```
v=spf1 ip4:11.11.11.11 a mx include:mailgun.org -all
```

Tools for check your mail server configuration (SPF/DKIM/SpamAssassin/Blacklist)

- https://www.mail-tester.com
- https://www.unlocktheinbox.com
- http://emailaudit.com
- http://dkimvalidator.com